# Meaning of `::` in Type Parameter?

Tags: scala, shapeless

Looking at Travis Brown's excellent blog post on [Type classes and generic derivation](https://meta.plasm.us/posts/2015/11/08/type-classes-and-generic-derivation/), I see the following method:

```
  implicit def hconsParser[H: Parser, T <: HList: Parser]: Parser[H :: T] =           
   new Parser[H :: T] {
    def apply(s: String): Option[H :: T] = s.split(",").toList match {
      case cell +: rest => for {
        head <- implicitly[Parser[H]].apply(cell)
        tail <- implicitly[Parser[T]].apply(rest.mkString(","))
      } yield head :: tail
    }
  }
```

What's the meaning of `H :: T` in `Parser[H :: T]`?

Also, how does this `case cell +: rest` handle the case where `s`, i.e. input to `apply` is empty?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`H :: T` is the infix form of the type `::[H, T]`, which is an `HList` with a head of type `H` and tail with type `T <: HList`. i.e. we're looking for a `Parser` for the type `::[H, T]`.

The infix usage is achieved like this, where `infix` can be any name:

```
scala> trait infix[A, B]

scala> def test[A, B](ab: A infix B) = ???
test: [A, B](ab: infix[A,B])Nothing
```

> Also, how does this `case cell +: rest` handle the case where `s`, i.e. input to `apply` is empty?

If `s` is an empty string, then `s.split(",").toList` will simply be a `List` with an empty string as its single element. `case cell +: rest` would then never run into an empty list.